# Java Scanner merging lines

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I am trying to use a for loop to ask for 3 pieces of user input which are then used to create a new instance of a class. It works for the first loop, but then the second loop I get this prompt on the console and it expects an integer input.

```
Enter the employee's name: adam
Enter their hours worked: 1
Enter the employee's pay rate: 1
Enter the employee's name: Enter their hours worked:
```

The code to input the data looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the employee's name: ");
            String employeeName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter their hours worked: ");
            int hoursWorked = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter the employee's pay rate: ");
            double payRate = input.nextDouble();
            employee[i] = new Payroll(employeeName, hoursWorked, payRate);
```

I saw other questions on this site that suggest I use input.next() instead of input.nextLine() but that solution did not work either. How do I get the input lines to separate like they should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 double payRate = input.nextDouble();
```

With `nextDouble`, the scanner just stops when finishes reading the `double` value, skipping the rest of the line, including `\n`.

The second time the `nextLine()` is called, it just reads the end of the double input you entered before, and continues with "*Enter their hours worked*", setting the `employeeName` empty after the first iteration.

As it is, your code could only work if you enter the value of the rate separated by the following employee name, like this (ugly):

```
  Enter the employee's pay rate: 3559 James
```

Make the scanner force reading the end of the "double" line at the end of the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    System.out.print("Enter the employee's name: ");
    String employeeName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter their hours worked: ");
    int hoursWorked = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the employee's pay rate: ");
    double payRate = input.nextDouble();
    employee[i] = new Payroll(employeeName, hoursWorked, payRate);
      
    //this
    if (i<4)
      input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: So you are saying there is automatically a /n at the end of the double input. For example, if i enter 42.3 the computer sees 42.3/n ?

Comment: When you push enter, yes. Try setting the rate and then the second name in the same line, like: 4666 James. The scanner will read it properly, as finishes at 4666 and will read the line in the second iteration (James) . That's nextLine()'s behaviour: read until \n is found

Comment: Note that \n is not a computer thing; Microsoft Word, NotePad, any text editor will show you the \n when you push enter, if you set to do so

Comment: I added "input.nextDouble() like you suggested and it works. Your explanation was very helpful. Thanks!